# Uglifyjs does not generate working map file when uglifying browserify output

Tags: browserify, uglifyjs

I've run browserify like this:

```
browserify js/app.js -d | exorcist js/bundle.js.map > js/bundle.js
```

When I load this in Chrome, the sources map file is fine. When I uglify it like this:

```
uglifyjs js/bundle.js --in-source-map js/bundle.js.map --source-map-url bundle2.js.map --source-map js/bundle2.js.map -o js/bundle2.js -p 1
```

The sources map file does not work. It tries to load sources from /js/js, instead of just from /js. I have fiddled with the -p parameter, and every other parameter that is documented on the commandline here:

```
https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to cd into the js directory and run the commands from there. Lame, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

`-p relative`

fixed the issue for me